# Can't remove access to google doc via api when not dealing with primary google email address

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api

Using the google document API, I am creating a document and added access rules.  In my system I only have one email address of this particular user.  Let's say it's johndoe@company.com.   Using that email address I add an access rule to my google doc.  Within google John Doe has two email addresses: a primary (johndoe@gmail.com) and a secondary (johndoe@company.com).  Google seems to be smart enough to make the association and when I look at the sharing for that document it shows John's primary email address (johndoe@gmail.com).

The problem is now I need to find that access rule and delete it, so I do a find (using the document API) to find the access rule by email address and since I only have the one email address (johndoe@company.com) google returns nothing.

Hopefully I'm missing a simple solution here such as:

- Can I request the access rule from google using the email address I
  have and using some undocumented feature have google look up the
  record via primary or secondary email address?
- Obtain the primary email address on access rule creation? (doesn't
  appear to be returned).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API, you just need to issue a DELETE request for the give acl. See "Removing sharing permissions". So, it should resolve the primary/secondary emails for you just like add.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/